# Can't decode GET parameter

Tags: php, url

I have a simple `url that pass two parameters. Name and cellphone. But when I use special characters, the parameter can't be decoded. It appears the ?? instead of the character.

I already tried use `urldecode($_GET['name']`), `rawurldecode`, `html_entity_decode`, `utf8_decode`, but none of this worked.

I have the `utf-8` meta tag in my HTML and I also tryed pass this as a header inside `php`, but it didn't work.

The code is like this

```
<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Could you post the querystring as well please?

Comment: Sorry. "name=Consult%F3rio" and the output I'm getting is Consult??rio

Comment: What are you expecting this to `echo`?

Comment: I'm expecting Consultório

Comment: `$_GET` is auto decoded.

Comment: Using the urldecoder here: https://www.urldecoder.org/ , "Consult%F3rio" decodes to Consultrio... the %F3 character is invalid.  Using the encoder, the correct encoding is Consult%C3%B3rio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have the use the correct function, which is `utf8_encode`:

```
<?php echo utf8_encode($_GET['name']); ?>
```

Output:

```
Consultório
```

The function `utf8_encode`:

> This function converts the string data from the ISO-8859-1 encoding to
>   UTF-8.

See the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Comment: Needless to say, if input data is not ISO-8859-1 then this solution doesn't apply at all. Honestly, in 2019 is easier to just use UTF-8 everywhere and stop caring about conversions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Totally agree, but in a world full of legacy code I suspect we'll be using conversions for a long time yet...

Answer (score 0):

```
name=Consult%F3rio
```

This is the good old ISO-8859-1 encoding for `Consultório` of the early days of the web. If the decoded version renders incorrectly, it's very likely that your application is not using ISO-8859-1 at all, thus there's no benefit in using it there either. If your app is using UTF-8, the simplest solution would be to switch entirely to UTF-8:

```
Consult%C3%B3rio
```

This is basically what you get with any builtin PHP function when fed with UTF-8 data because they work at byte level:

```
var_dump(rawurlencode('Consultório')); // string(16) "Consult%C3%B3rio"
```

If this happens to be third-party data you can't control, please check [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275314/13508).